# jQuery Rich Text Editor

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, richtextbox, richtext, rich-text-editor

I'm currently using TinyMCE 3 on a site, but have noticed it's pretty bloated (many files to download, etc.). I'm working on improving the site's download time, etc. One of the things I want to do is replace TinyMCE with a more lightweight solution.

My requirements are basic:

- Bold
- Italic
- Unordered list
- Ordered list
- Blockquote
- Outdent
- Indent
- Cut, Copy, Paste (can live without these)
- Undo & Redo (can live without these)

The editor is not used to create complex layouts or anything. It's just used in simple forms, like for emails and product/service descriptions. Just very basic formatting requirements.

Finally, something hosted on Google CDN would be a big plus.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can strip tinymce down massively.

Just show the icons you want and delete all the plugin folders that contain functionality for the icons you don't want.

Delete the themes/skins you don't want.

Delete all the pages relating to the image/file manager.

The core isn't that big.

Answer (score 3):

[Hallo](http://hallojs.org/) is quite a simple rich text editor built as a jQuery UI widget. MIT license and should provide the features you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend http://ckeditor.com/. I like the easy file integration with http://ckfinder.com/ file manager. Last time I checked, TinyMCE charged for most file manager plugins, or you had to hack around to get something working.

Here is an [article](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/tinymce-vs-ckeditor) on some reasons to try it instead.

Comment: IMHO going from TinyMCE to CKE is a step backwards.... CKE is just as bloated as TinyMCE - but it's also considerably less slick and more buggy (personal opinion only)

Comment: why? I see it's very full featured (way more than what I need), but I am curious why you recommend it.

Comment: Well I used TinyMCE for a couple years before moving to CKEditor and unless it has changed drastically in that time, I would not go back to it. I find CKEditor plenty slick. Personal opinion as well. Didn't read the lightweight requirement until now, and I do not know how CKEditor stands in that regard.

Comment: is tinyMCE and CKEditor free for using commercial purpose on a website ?